# Why is the main method in Java always static?

Tags: java, static-methods

Onetime I forgot to put the static keyword for the main method in my java class.
And the program did not work . So the question is why we always need to mark the main method as static?

Answer (score -2):

When you call any method from the same class you have the main you need to make it static or build an instance of that class `new Class().method()`. In the case of `public static void main (String[] args)` it's explained here [link](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-we-use-static-in-public-static-void-main-String-args-in-Java)